# Do AOP violate layered architecture for enterprise apps?

Tags: spring-mvc, aop, n-tier-architecture

The question(as stated in the title) comes to me as recently i was looking at Spring MVC 3.1 with annotation support and also considering DDD for an upcoming project. In the new Spring any POJO with its business methods can be annotated to act as controller, all the concerns that i would have addressed within a Controller class can be expressed exclusively through the annotations.

So,  technically i can take any class and wire it to act as controller , the java code is free from any controller specific code, hence the java code could deal with things like checking security , starting txn etc. So will such a class belong to Presentation or Application layer ??

Taking that argument even further , we can pull out things like security, txn mgmt and express them through annotations , thus the java code is now that of the domain object. Will that mean we have fused together the 2 layers? Please clarify

Comment: What does AOP have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't take any POJO and make it a controller. The controller's job is get inputs from the browser, call services, prepare the model for the view, and return the view to dispatch to. It's still a controller. Instead of configuring it through XML and method overrides, you configure it through annotations, that's all.

The code is very far from being free from any controller specific code. It still uses ModelAndView, BindingResult, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'll approach the question's title, regarding AOP:

AOP does not violate "layered architecture", specifically because by definition it is adding application-wide functionality *regardless* of the layer the functionality is being used in. The canonical AOP example is logging: not a layer, but a functionality--all layers do logging.

To sort-of tie in AOP to your question, consider transaction management, which may be handled via Spring's AOP mechanism. "Transactions" themselves are not specific to any layer, although any given app may only *require* transactions in only a single layer. In that case, AOP doesn't violate layered architecture because it's only being applied to a single layer.

In an application where transactions may cross layers IMO it still doesn't violate any layering principles, because *where* the transactions live isn't really relevant: all that matters is that "this chunk of functionality must be transactional". Even if that transaction spans several app boundaries.

In fact, I'd say that using AOP in such a case specifically *preserves* layers, because the TX code isn't mechanically reproduced across all those layers, and no single layer needs to wonder (a) if it's being called in a transactional context, or (b) *which* transactional context it's in.